# Generate log for each script with py.test

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a simple way to generate a log file for each script tested, pytest already does this but all in one file, is there a way to split them up in each test script's directory, e.g. If I have 
dir1 containing script1
dir2 containing script2
I don't want the log to all be in one file, I want two separate ones in dir1 and dir2.

Answer (score 0):

In each script, you might want to use file input/output. If the file doesn't exist, the function would create one for writing. In each script you want to test, put in something like this:

```
with open("log file name 1", "a") as log:
    log.write("whatever you want to log in here")
```

Putting something like this in each script will probably save more time than trying to use a third-party library or trying to find some other way to do it in the short run.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i concluded that best solution for my problem is separte pytest commands , example `py.test <script_name>` or change the py.test initial configuration (with adding cmd line options or markers)

Comment: Good luck! I hope your project goes well!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to store text which you normally see in console in filesystem,
try playing with `pytest_collectreport`, `pytest_report_teststatus` hooks. You can get nodeid (name of test module/function) and output text from them.

If you'd like to store logs from loggers (logging module), you can use [pytest-logger](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-logger) to make a log file[s] for every testcase separately to store loggers output. Directory structure is made automatically, user only needs to pass logger names and levels.